# Inconsistent Query Results between Google Apps Script and BigQuery

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-bigquery

**Problem encountered:**

I am experiencing an issue where queries executed via Google Apps Script are **intermittently** returning no results. However, when the same queries are run directly in BigQuery, they consistently return the expected results.

**What was expected:**

The expectation is that queries executed via Google Apps Script should return the same results as when they are executed directly in BigQuery, given that both are executed using the same account and permissions.

**Steps to reproduce:**

- Execute a query via Google Apps Script that is known to return results in BigQuery.
- Observe that the query **sometimes** returns no results when executed via Google Apps Script.
- Execute the same query directly in BigQuery and observe that it **consistently** returns the expected results.

**Other information:**

No error messages are displayed when this issue occurs; the Google Apps Script simply returns no results. This issue seems to occur randomly. However, it might happens more often in the morning for some reasons.

I have tried reviewing the scripts and queries for errors and also checked for any potential issues with access permissions, but haven't found a solution or encountered others with a similar issue. What is tricky is that it will happen randomly so I suspect an API issue or an overload on servers due to many queries in queue.

Here a sample script to help you potentially distinguish a potential issue/solution.

```
projectId='my_project_ID';

function onOpen(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  .createMenu("Loading BQ")
  .addItem("Get delivery and visit data", 'getresult_query1')
  .addToUi();
}

function mapToArray(rows) {
    var data = new Array(rows.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
      var cols = rows[i].f;
      data[i] = new Array(cols.length);
      for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) {
        data[i][j] = cols[j].v;
      }
  }
  return data;
};

function getresult_query1() {
  var sheet =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Context');
  var campaignName = sheet.getRange('C6').getValue()

   var request = {query: 'My_query',
     location: 'EU',
     useLegacySql: false,
     timeoutMs: 1000000
   };

  var queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.query(request, projectId);
  var sheet =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Overall'); 
  sheet.getRange(7,2,1,9).setValue(''); 
  if(queryResults.rows){
    sheet.getRange(7,2,queryResults.rows.length,9).setValues(mapToArray(queryResults.rows));
    }else{
    sheet.getRange(7,2).setValue('No results'); 
  }
```

Thank you for your help,

Zion

Comment: When you review the query runs in the bigquery console history, did you compare the runtime to the timeout in your app script code?

Comment: Yeah, its usually lower than 1000000 MS. It takes usually 10min max on BQ console.
Do you think increasing the timeoutMs could help resolve that?
I already did, I think it was originally 500000 MS.